Constrain Transform to Face
Is there a way to constrain transforms to faces?
I am trying to move the selected vert in the image to the right a little (I am aware this can be accomplished with the knife tool, but I'd prefer to simply be able to directly nudge the vert).


Select one of the faces that the vertex is on and click the + button on the TransformOrientation dropdown. That will add a new Face orientation as shown below.

You can then select your vertex and use G + Shift-Z to move the vertex around on the face.

